# Is there a penalty for failing an ambush?

Tags: for-the-king

If a character attempts to ambush an enemy from the world map and rolls less-than-perfectly, is there any penalty? Or does combat simply begin as usual?

Comment: Not realted; Just a little question that has nothing to do with the question, how did you post , then 10 ,minutes later another post? I though it was 60 minutes wait time.

Comment: @GamerM not sure, I had no idea there was a wait time, and I had two questions about For The King, so I just posted them :)

Answer (score 2):

Enemies seem to get at least one free attack in when you FAIL an Ambush.
Keep in mind this is just something I have noticed and I can't find any info to prove it, but [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FTK/comments/8fna8q/question_about_the_ambush_option_before_a_battle/) seems to confirm it